# Java BufferedReader behavior in CSV vs TXT file

Tags: java, csv, text-files, bufferedreader

If i try to read a CSV file called `csv_file.csv`. The problem is that when i read lines with `BufferedReader.readLine()` it skips the first line with months. But when i rename the file to `csv_file.txt` it reads it allright and it's not skipping the first line.

Is there an undocumented "feature" of BufferedReader that i'm not aware?

Example of file:

```
Months, SEP2010, OCT2010, NOV2010
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
aaa,,sdf,"12,456",bla bla bla, xsaffadfafda
and so on, and so on, "10,00", xxx, xxx
```

The code:

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(UploadSupport.TEMPORARY_FILES_PATH+fileName);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
String line = br.readLine();
String months[] = line.split(",");
while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
    /*parse other lines*/
}
```

Comment: Show your code.  BufferedReader has no awareness of the file or filename, just the contents it reads from another Reader.

Comment: i updated the description of my question... and i know that the java doesn't care for the file name, but i get different behavior for different file names

Comment: It seems far-fetched that that the change in behavior is due to the extension.  How are you renaming the file (through the OS rename or by resaving through same app or by using a different editor)?  Some further debugging is probably called for.  What happens if you change the extension back to ".csv"? What if you save the file to a ".txt" extension originally (from Excel)? What is the contents for the line that is thrown out?

Comment: I change the extension in windows explorer, simple file rename. And if i change it back to csv it does the same thing, it jumps over the first line. And i honestly have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: What library is `UploadSupport` from?

Comment: This may be extreme but what about getting us a hexdump of the first 2 lines?

Comment: `UploadSupport` is my own class that i created and `TEMPORARY_FILES_PATH` is a constant

Comment: @Andrew White : I checked both files and are identical... new line characters are the same

Comment: Could you update your example and replace `br.readLine();` with your loop? Careless use of readLine could be the culprit. For example, `while (br.readLine() != null) { String line = br.readLine();}` would skip every other line.

Comment: Very interesting.  What OS? What file system type?

Comment: @jt : the while loop is after i read the first line, and after that i loop through the rest of the lines with `while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){ /*do stuff*/ } but i will update it

Comment: @Bert F : Windows 7 ultimate 64bit, NTFS file system.

Comment: @Gabriel - Thanks.  I posted a class and my results below.  Care to try it?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's bad practice to use the `InputStreamReader(InputStream in)` constructor, which uses the "default charset". You should specify the charset explicitly.

This can hardly explain to your problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

No difference on my system:

- Windows Vista SP2 (32-bit)
- NTFS
- JDK 1.6.0_17

Output:

```
Creating C:\workspace\Sandbox\src\data.txt

Reading C:\workspace\Sandbox\src\data.txt
Skipped: 'Months, SEP2010, OCT2010, NOV2010'
First read: 'col1, col2, col3, col4, col5'

Reading C:\workspace\Sandbox\src\data.csv
Skipped: 'Months, SEP2010, OCT2010, NOV2010'
First read: 'col1, col2, col3, col4, col5'

Reading C:\workspace\Sandbox\src\data.txt
Skipped: 'Months, SEP2010, OCT2010, NOV2010'
First read: 'col1, col2, col3, col4, col5'
```

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class BuffReadTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String baseFilename = args[0] + "/data";
        try {
            final File txtFile = new File(baseFilename+".txt");
            final File csvFile = new File(baseFilename+".csv");

            if (txtFile.exists())   txtFile.delete();
            if (csvFile.exists())   csvFile.delete();
            createFile(txtFile.getAbsolutePath());

            readFile(txtFile.getAbsolutePath());

            txtFile.renameTo(csvFile);
            readFile(csvFile.getAbsolutePath());

            csvFile.renameTo(txtFile);
            readFile(txtFile.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createFile(final String filename)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("\nCreating "+filename);
        final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(filename);
        pw.println("Months, SEP2010, OCT2010, NOV2010");
        pw.println("col1, col2, col3, col4, col5");
        pw.println("aaa,,sdf,\"12,456\",bla bla bla, xsaffadfafda");
        pw.println("and so on, and so on, \"10,00\", xxx, xxx");
        pw.close();
    }

    private static void readFile(final String filename)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        System.out.println("\nReading "+filename);
        final FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(filename);
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        final String skipped = br.readLine();
        final String first = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Skipped: '"+skipped+"'");
        System.out.println("First read: '"+first+"'");
        br.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the file extension of a file is ignored by Java (actually the only thing that usually cares about file extensions is Windows). I would guess you have some sort of newline/very subtle coding issue causing the problem you see.

Answer (score 0):

Is your editor doing something special while saving the file? Are you working on Windows? (there are some Newline differences between linux & windows, although I never ran into trouble using Java)

Comment: i use eclipse on windows 7 and i have standard line ending CR LF. and the csv file was created by saving an excel file as csv file... but i'm looking at it in notepad++ and there is nothing weird about the file